# stop and start coroutines in C# script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing a small project and I have a problem with coroutines.
The project has a coroutine that performs such and such an action and is executed again. at one moment, by pressing the button, you need to stop the coroutine, and then after a second start it again. Everything would be fine, but when the coroutine is launched, the actions are repeated, that is, the coroutine is repeated several times, the last one stopped and the new one. Is it possible to fix this somehow? Or do you have to write a lot of code?

Code:

```
public float Numbers;
public float Gold;

    public void BuyPerson()
    {
        if (Gold >= 10)
        {
            Gold -= 10;
            StartCoroutine(_Coroutine());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator _Coroutine() 
    {
        Numbers = Numbers++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        StartCoroutine(_Coroutine());
    }

    public void OnClick()
    {
        StopCoroutine(_Coroutine());

        StartCoroutine(StartCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator _Coroutine() 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        
        StartCoroutine(_Coroutine());
    }
```

I tried to stop _Coroutine and start it again, but it still repeats the action several times (depending on the number of clicks)

Comment: Change: `StartCoroutine(_Coroutine());` to `if (Gold>)0 StartCoroutine(_Coroutine());` ?

Comment: BTW: When/Where is `Gold` assigned an initial value ?

Comment: @luuk, Either I don't understand something or it won't work.
If you press the button several times, the action will also be repeated ... I considered the Gold value unnecessary and did not specify it

Comment: OK, never mind, I misread the question, and still missing the implementation of  `StartCoroutine`.  I was misreading because I thought it should not get started when Gold was too low.

Comment: in general, when I click on a button bound to OnClick(), _coroutine should pause for a second and then continue running. but 2 coroutines are launched at once. As I understand it, I need to run the main _coroutine, and I run the duplicate and the original.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing the result from `StartCoroutine(...)` within a `Coroutine` object. You can then pass that result into `StopCoroutine(...)` which will then stop the Coroutine you have started. Otherwise, when you call `StopCoroutine(_Coroutine())` you are stopping a new Coroutine, instead of referencing the one you have already started.

For example:

```
private Coroutine coroutine;

IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);
  coroutine = StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());
}

void OnClick()
{
  if (coroutine != null) StopCoroutine(coroutine);

  coroutine = StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());
}
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it and solved my problem with While and bool, that is, the coroutine now looks like this:

'''
public floatr numbers;
public bool _bool;

```
    while(_bool)
    {
        numbers++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
```

'''
The coroutine will restart with While, when While disables the action, it will stop and then run again on another part of the script.